# How to tokenise "i.e." sentences in parenthesis? (Python)

Tags: string, python-2.7, nltk, tokenize

I want to tokenise sentences from text as shown in the image, include the one in the (i.E.) parenthesis. It splits sentences shown in the green colours in the image.

[image: Here is my text]
I have tried the nltk tokenised function and the regular expression. Could you please give me suggestion? Thank you.

```
import nltk
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
infile = open("textfile.txt", "r")

for line in infile:
    line =  line.strip()
    print tokenizer.tokenize(line)
    
infile.close()

#partial RE code
sentences  = re.split(r'(?<=!w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s', text)
```

Here is the example text:

> Yes it is real and there is countless evidence of it The world is shouting     to our ears about the climate alteration humans are causing. The evidence of changing climate and a accelerating pace to mayhem is evident. First of all the thermometers around the globe have a average temperature reading, this reading is going up to unprecedented levels since measuring stated back in the 1880. Also levels of CO2 are measured since 1958 and they are consistently going up. From the ice containing air from other ages it has been concluded that CO2 levels are the highest in 600 thousand years. From fossil records scientists have concluded that probably humans played a important role in the extinction of all big vertebrate animals around the globe (i.E. Mammoths, bisons etc. ). People that don't believe in CO2 warming effect, have to stop believing things and start looking, Venus a very similar planet to earth, has a very high concentration of CO2 and in consequence it has a temperature of over 400 C.
>
> All of these is no mumble jumble they are plain facts and figures, all pointing to disaster if we don't change our behavior. Please people wake up!

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but don't feed the sentence tokenizer one line at a time; it needs more context to identify sentence boundaries properly. Feed it the whole file, or at least entire paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you almost what you need

```
sentences  = re.split(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z]{2,}\)?\.) |\(', text)
```

Maybe you can then replace trailing ")." with ".".

That won't match brackets in sentences though and need to add 2 more or conditions for ! and ?. I just omitted them for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying sentence boundaries is a tough problem, and the nltk's statistical tokenizer does a good job with lots of weird cases. Identifying sentence boundaries by hand might take care of *this* error, but will make many more mistakes elsewhere. If you're concerned about small systematic errors like this, I would pre-process the text to help the tokenizer.

In this case, the problem is that `i.e.` is normally written with a comma afterwards (and without capitalization, but lowercasing it doesn't solve the problem): `(i.e., mammoths, bisons etc.)`. So you can get proper tokenization by in effect copy-editing the text, to add the missing comma:

```
text = re.sub(r"\b(i\.e\.)(\s+)", r"\1,\2", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```